# Easiest way to create a table with Zend_Pdf

Tags: php, zend-framework

What's the easyiest way to create a table with Zend_Pdf?

Until now, i realized tables with horizontal and vertical lines. Is there no other solution for tables?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this project in SF: http://zendpdftable.sourceforge.net/

However it's still not very practical, compared to other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I've also found a [Zend_Pdf_Helper](https://github.com/btm6084/Zend_PDF_Helper) gitHub project that maybe can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

From what i have read there is no easy way to do this. The closest you will get is by using the [shape drawing primitives](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.drawing.html#zend.pdf.drawing.shape-drawing) in the Zend_Pdf API or (probably better) by switching to another PDF library entirely.

Answer (score 0):

XSL:FO combined with FOP handles tables very nicely.  The downside is that it is an external too, seems to be slightly dated, and documentation for it is not the greatest.  This posting of mine might help: http://grover.open2space.com/content/creating-pdf-code-fop